# Trying to make a list in the following format using linux bash commands (awk,cut, or any solution)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I've been trying to make one list of my local servers containing the credentials to automate process on my side. Here's the file I have right now:

```
head hosts-only.txt
192.168.2.101
192.168.2.102
192.168.2.103
192.168.2.105
192.168.2.107

head user-only.txt
admin
tomcat
oracle

head pass-only.txt
123456
secret
secure
```

ofc, password are not real below, just using them as an example. Now, what I am trying to accomplish is getting one 'list.txt' containing the information in the following format:

```
192.168.2.101:admin:123456
192.168.2.102:tomcat:secret
192.168.2.103:oracle:secure
```

Any help would be very appreciated,

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at

```
paste -d: hosts-only.txt user-only.txt pass-only.txt
```